# Getting a sub-list containing list[i+1] where list[i] is a specific value

Tags: parsing, python-3.x

This is a bit of a tough one to phrase properly.

Say I had the list

```
['There,', 'calls', 'the', 'mariner', 'there', 'comes', 'a', 'ship', 'over',
'the', 'line', 'But', 'how', 'can', 'she', 'sail', 'with', 'no', 'wind', 'in',
'her', 'sails', 'and', 'no', 'tide.', 'See...', 'onward', 'she', 'comes', 'Onwards',
'she', 'nears,', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'sun', 'See...', 'she', 'has', 'no', 'crew',]
```

How can I extract from it the list

```
['sail', 'comes', 'nears', 'has']
```

That is, every element that comes immediately after a "she"? Can it be done with a list comprehension?

Comment: Explaination for the down/closevotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for all cases:

```
[li[i+1] for i in range(len(li)-1) if li[i]=='she']
```

with `li` being your list...

For larger lists, you can either use the [pairwise recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in itertools or this:

```
def pairs(li):
    # Python 2 -- use izip instead of zip
    from itertools import islice
    for this_item, next_item in zip(li, islice(li, 1, None)):
        yield this_item, next_item
```

Then your result is:

```
list(that for this, that in pairs(li) if this=='she')
```

Which has the advantage of not building intermediate lists.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are a couple edge cases in this list comp, e.g.

```
[word for i, word in enumerate(lst[1:], 1) if lst[i-1]=="she"]
# misses the first match if lst[0] == 'she'

[lst[i+1] for i,word in enumerate(lst) if word=='she']
# IndexError if lst[-1] == 'she'
```

I would suggest using regex instead.

```
import re
words_string = ' '.join(lst)
pat = re.compile(r"""
         \bshe\s      # literal 'she '
         (\w+)\b      # match next word up to the word break""",
                 flags=re.X)
target = pat.findall(words_string)
```

Comment: Since when you `' '.join(list)` the resulting string will not start with a space -- the regex has the same problem. It won't match the first 'she' at the start of the string. Suggest `re.findall(r'\bshe\s(\w+)\b'...`

Comment: @dawg thanks! My head still spins in circles about the difference between `\b` and `\s` since they seem like they should be the same! Then again I have to check my quickref each time I use `\s` or `\w` because I forget if it's `"space" and "word"` or `"string" and "whitespace"`

Comment: Well `\s` is a literal white space character which all have width. The string `she word` does not start with a space, so that string would not match the regex `\sshe` The regex metacharacter `\b` is a shortcut for the following assertion of the sero width test of a character before the spot being one of `\w|\W` and the next being the opposite `\W|\w`